# I have an array of objects. These objects have arrays of integers and I can't access them within the array

Tags: c++, arrays

**This is my class**

```
class Process {
public:
    Process();
    void createBurstArray(int *bursts, int sizeOfArray);
    void createIOArray(int *IO, int capacity);
    int *burstArray;
    int *ioArray;
    int currentBurst;
    int currentIO;
    int currentState;
};

Process::Process()
{

}

void Process::createBurstArray(int *bursts, int capacity){

    burstArray = new int[capacity];
    burstArray = bursts;

};

void Process::createIOArray(int *IO, int capacity) {

    ioArray = new int[capacity];
    ioArray = IO;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)

};

void main(){

int processOneBursts[7] = { 12,10,15,11,9,10,11 };
int processOneIO[6] = { 44,52,21,42,31,77 };

Process processes[9];
Process one;
processes[0] = one;

one.createBurstArray(processOneBursts, 7);
one.createIOArray(processOneIO, 6);
```

}
When I try accessing the ioArray

```
one.ioArray[1]
```

I get the value stored in the ioArray at index 1, butw hen I try accessing the ioArra through my object array index it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << processes[i].ioArray[i] << endl;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "it doesn't work"? What do you mean by that? Why do you use the same index for both arrays? You have actually allocated memory and assigned the pointer to `ioArray`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Finally, why are you using pointers and not `std::vector`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the program crashes and gives me "Exception thrown at 0x01333540 in FCFS Process Scheduler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC."

Comment: Obviously, Your program is a excellent road for segmentation fault. Have you initialize the integer array before you are accessing it in a loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and the index "i" used in the above post is somewhat irrelevant, I should be using some other value to access the array but I figured that was irrelevant to the problem itself.

Comment: The index issue *might* be irrelevant, but when it comes to pointers and *undefined behavior* (which is most likely what you have) then all details are relevant. Like I said, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Also you should be using a debugger to catch the crash in action to learn exactly where it happens, as well as look at all involved variables to see if they look valid (indexes and pointers are important here). Lastly: You *have* initialized `ioArray` to point to some valid memory?

Comment: Are you deleting `ioArray` at some point? Do you have a destructor for `Process`?

Comment: Looking at your edit, where does `processOneIO` come from? And when and where do you call the `createIOArray` function in relation to your crash? And you have a memory leak in `createIOArray`, the pointer given to you by `new int[capacity]` is overwritten by the next assignment, making you lose the first pointer. Are you perhaps doing `delete [] ioArray` anywhere and then try to free some statically allocated memory? Really, without a proper MCVE it's only possible to guess badly.

Comment: After your latest edit, the index issue is *very* relevant. Your loop as you show it goes through all *nine* elements in the `process` array, and then you use the same index for the `ioArray` pointer, but that only points to an array of *six* elements. Oh and that's not all, as you don't seem to be initializing any other elements of the `process` array. And you still don't show if you do `delete[]` on the pointer, or where the crash actually happens. There are so many unknowns and so many chances for UB.

Comment: I agree that it would be an issue but the program crashes even if I explicitly say processes[i].ioArray[1]. Or better yet, forget the for loop. I can say processes[1].ioArray[2] and it will crash.

Comment: The code you show only initializes `processes[0]`. All other elements in the `processes` array are uninitialized, and will have *indeterminate* values. Using them will lead to *undefined behavior* and possible crashes. And are you *sure* it's the array access that causes the crash? Have you used a debugger to find out?

Comment: Does this mean that the debugger doesn't know where the arrays are? processes[1] {burstArray=0xcccccccc {???} ioArray=0xcccccccc {???} currentBurst=1 ...}

Answer (score 0):

You are object of the class with default constructor which means all the elements in the class will be uninitialized including the element  **int *ioArray;**.

And you are trying to access ioArray in the for loop which is road set to segmentation fault.

To correct this, you must initialize the element before using them.

Also, Your below function is problematic.

```
 void Process::createIOArray(int *IO, int capacity) {
 ioArray = new int[capacity]; 

 ioArray = IO;
}
```

This is a memory leak, since you have assign ioArray to IO ,new int[capacity] memory will not be freed.

**Solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Process {
public:
    Process();
    void createBurstArray(int sizeOfArray);
    void createIOArray(int capacity);
    int *burstArray;
    int *ioArray;
    int currentBurst;
    int currentIO;
    int currentState;
// Don't forget to delete burstArray, ioArray in destructor.
};

void Process::createIOArray(int capacity) {
ioArray = new int[capacity];
};

void Process::createBurstArray(int sizeOfArray) {
burstArray = new int[sizeOfArray];
};
Process::Process(){

    createIOArray(10);
    createBurstArray(10);
    // Similarly you have to initialize other members of the class
}

int main()
{

    Process processes[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << processes[i].ioArray[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do initialize the array before the for loop. I've added the function I use to initialize it.

Comment: Your function was wrong and was prone to errors, Please see updated solution.

Comment: Ok but now these arrays are empty? Is there a way to createBurstArray ot createIOArray with an existing array of value? I need to pass **processOneIO** array to it

Comment: Yes, once you assign memory to array. Perform memcpy from existing array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Process {
public:
//    Process();
void createBurstArray(int *bursts, int sizeOfArray);
void createIOArray(int *IO, int capacity);
int *burstArray;
int *ioArray;
int currentBurst;
int currentIO;
int currentState;
};

int main()
{
Process p[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   p[i].ioArray = new int[1];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   p[i].ioArray[0] = i;
}


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << p[i].ioArray[0] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

This works, i think you didn't initialize the dynamic array.